# Creating dynamic tabsets in Shiny app gives an error on ggploty

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, shiny

I have a problem with a Shiny app that I don’t understand. I think it is a conceptual problem with reactive objects, but I am not sure.

The app creates a tab based on the names of the columns of a dataset using uiOutput. And then I create dynamically the corresponding plotlyOutput within an Observe.

The problem is that when I change the dataset, their columns change their names as well, and it seems that the app remembers the last entrance and tries to render an object with data that it is not there anymore.

The result is a warning like this one:

> Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'ggplotly'
>   applied to an object of class "NULL" Stack trace (innermost first):
>       79: ggplotly
>       78: func
>       77: origRenderFunc
>       76: output$tabPlot_a1
>        1: runApp

I’ve created a Shiny app to recreate the error, just open it, go to Tab 2 and then change the “prefix” to “b”, for example.

The tabs change, but it gives the warning.

Any hint on what's going on?

The code:

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")
library("plotly")
library("ggplot2")

shinyApp(
  ui=shinyUI(dashboardPage(skin = "blue",
                           dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),
                           dashboardSidebar(
                             textInput("prefix", label = "Columns prefix", value = "a")
                           ),
                           dashboardBody(
                             tabBox(
                               tabPanel("Tab 1", "This is tab number 1", tableOutput("tabData")),
                               tabPanel("Tab 2", "This is tab number 2", uiOutput("tabPlot"))
                             )
                           )
  ))
  ,
  server=shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    create_data <- reactive({
      x<-seq(-2,2,length.out=100)
      y1<-dnorm(x)
      y2<-dunif(x)
      y3<-dexp(x,2)
      y4<-dbeta(x,1,2)
      data<-data.frame(x,y1,y2,y3,y4)
      names(data)<-c("x",paste(input$prefix,1:4,sep=""))
      data
    })

    output$tabData<-renderTable({
      data<-create_data()
      data
    })

    output$tabPlot = renderUI({
      data <- create_data()
      tabnames<-names(data)[-1]
      do.call(tabsetPanel,
              lapply(tabnames,function(s){
                call("tabPanel",s,call('plotlyOutput',outputId=paste0("tabPlot_",s)))
              })
      )
    })

    observe({
      data <- create_data()
      tabnames<-names(data)[-1]
      lapply(tabnames, function(s){output[[paste0("tabPlot_",as.character(s))]] <- renderPlotly({
        data <- create_data()
        if (as.character(s) %in% names(data)){
          data.plot<-data[c("x",as.character(s))]
          p <- plotthis(data.plot)
          z <- ggplotly(p)          
        }else{
          z<-NULL
        }
        z
      })})
    })

    plotthis<-function(data){
      names(data)<-c("x","y")
      p<-ggplot(data=data,aes(x=x,y=y))+
        geom_line()
      p
    }

  })
)
```

Comment: It has something to do with the NULL in the obsere if/else loop, although this does not explain the fact it returns to the previous dataset. I am not sure why you need the if/else loop, is this for the situation no prefix is chosen?

Comment: If I remove the if/else then the error is that the column is not found in the dataset. It is like it remembers the old tab selection of a1 and tries to apply to the new dataset (which have b1, b2,..) and does not find it.

Comment: Warning: Error in [.data.frame: undefined columns selected
Stack trace (innermost first):
    84: [.data.frame
    83: [ [#49]
    82: ggplotly [#49]
    81: func
    80: origRenderFunc
    79: output$tabPlot_a1
     4: <Anonymous>
     3: do.call
     2: print.shiny.appobj
     1: <Promise>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like one of the the old output nodes (with the previous name) is still being activated, and the guards you built in are not helping even though it seems like they should. I tried a few ways to fix it, like fixing the names of the output nodes to not change, or changing to selecting the columns from `data` numerically, but in the end something much simpler fixed it - isolating one of the `create_data()` statements. That suppresses the unwanted output node activation.

Here is the code for that `observe` - I get no `ggplotly NULL` warnings when I add the `isolate`. Note that only one line needed to be changed:

```
observe({
  data <- create_data()
  tabnames<-names(data)[-1]
  lapply(tabnames,function(s){output[[paste0("tabPlot_",as.character(s))]]<-renderPlotly({
    data <- isolate(create_data())
    if (as.character(s) %in% names(data)){
      data.plot<-data[c("x",as.character(s))]
      p <- plotthis(data.plot)
      z <- ggplotly(p)          
    }else{
      z<-NULL
    }
    z
  })
})
```

As an aside, I learned a lot with this post, I had no idea that `observe` could generate output nodes like this. But I do wonder if you are being too clever by renaming the data columns and output nodes on the fly like this. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Fist, thank for your comments. This is just an example, the original shiny app what it really does is to read an input file, read the columns and then plot each column individually as in the example (so it is not a "create_data", is a "read_data". It is not a renaming issue, it is that there are different datasets with different columns.

Comment: So does this help? I did put quite a lot of work into it.

Comment: Also, yesterday I found out that removing completely the line create_data() fix the problem, try it. All seems to work fine with no more warnings or error. But it does not make too many sense to me, actually, the renderPlotly should read the dataset with create_data again in order to know the column names, because the plot is generated on the fly when you clic on the tab and not when you change the dataset columns. But looks like the lapply is able to use the variable data created at the begining of the observe and use it.